# What's the meaning of "have received" this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

"Some of them have received industrial development"
To be more specific, what's "have received" meaning in above sentence?
The context is about some materials.

Comment: I suggest to include the paragraph or source of the sentence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, the meaning of "have received" is pretty literal.  It would mean that the object is being given industrial development, possibly being improved on.